# How to use Deploy to container Plugin in declarative pipeline

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Could someone help me understand how I should use the "Deploy to container Plugin" plugin in my declarative pipeline?

And tried this way and nothing ... I don't understand how to use order the parameters in the line.

```
deploy container: tomcat8, url:"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8082/", credentialsId: "test", war: 'target/app.war', contextPath: '/app1'
```

edit:

this is the doc:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/deploy/#deploy-deploy-warear-to-a-container

edit2: i try_

```
deploy adapters: tomcat8(url:"http://x.x.x.x:8080/", credentialsId: "asdasd"), war: 'target/app.war', contextPath: '/app'
```

and i have :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Undefined symbol ‘tomcat8’
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:448)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.UninstantiatedDescribable.instantiate(UninstantiatedDescribable.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:372)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:318)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:259)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {adapters=@tomcat8(...
```

Comment: Try to use snippet generator to get the correct syntax (link "Pipeline Syntax" at bottom of project configuration).

Comment: Thx! i had a old version of the plugin and after update i can use the snippet generator.

Answer (score 1):

`adapters` parameter is of type `list`. You can check the type signatures [Deploy to container](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/deploy/#deploy-deploy-warear-to-a-container). Following is the correct syntax:

```
    deploy adapters: [tomcat8(url: 'http://localhost:8666/', 
                              credentialsId: 'tomcat')], 
                     war: 'target/*.war',
                     contextPath: 'app'
```